# Anandroid app that can notify user immediately if a website is updated

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

How to create an android app that can notify user immediately if something on a website is updated.
Suppose I have a blogger blog like http://abcd.blogspot.com So what I want is that whenever I post a new topic on my blog that topic notification should be pushed on to every android device that has my app installed. Please explain in detail if possible And I am not able to use PHP because its a blogger blog.

Answer (score 0):

Use your blogs RSS and parse the output which is located [here](http://abcd.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default). Its better to do this on another server application not on the client. This way you can use something like [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com) when someone installed your application and send push each time new post detected by your server application.